# Create vocabulary of corpus from multiple txt files

Tags: r, dictionary, tm

I am playing around with `R`. I want to create my `dictionary` from a `txt` file. I have 2 .txt files as:

```
#1.txt
 sky,
 sun

#2.txt
blue,
bright
```

To load these 2 files in `R`, I am doing the following:

```
library(tm)
txt_files = list.files(pattern = '*.txt');
data = lapply(txt_files, read.table, sep = ",")
 #here I get error
  Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
   line 2 did not have 2 elements
   In addition: Warning message:
   In FUN(c("1.txt", "2.txt")[[1L]], ...) :
   incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on '1.txt'
dict <- c(data)
#dict <- c("sky","blue","bright","sun") // original dictionary, want to replace this by above method
docs <- c(D1 = "The sky is blue.", D2 = "The sun is bright.", D3 = "The sun in the sky is bright.")
dd <- Corpus(VectorSource(docs))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(dd, control = list(weighting = weightTfIdf,dictionary = dict))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
'x' must be atomic
```

Can anybody tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: After your _first_ error there is no 'data' object, so the line `dict<-c(data)` actually assigns the function `data` to the name 'dict'. It all goes wrong from there.

Comment: @BondedDust I know that. How can I load the txt files in data is the challenge.

Comment: Posting a clear problem set would be a better start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should use `read.table` for those irregular data files. Why not just use `readLines()` instead

```
txt_files <- list.files(pattern = '*.txt');
data <- lapply(txt_files, readLines)
dict <- gsub(",$","", unlist(data))

docs <- c(D1 = "The sky is blue.", D2 = "The sun is bright.", D3 = "The sun in the sky is bright.")
dd <- Corpus(VectorSource(docs))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(dd, 
    control = list(weighting = weightTfIdf,dictionary = dict)) 

inspect(dtm)
```

Note we had to remove the training comma ourselves with this method, but that's pretty easy.

Comment: @user2481422 The dictionary is just fine. You get that error because no document included "blue" or "bright". If you want to match those, you should include a step to remove punctuation. "bright." (with a period) will not match "bright"